# Subtable labels not updating in body of article

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, labels

I want to refer to "Table 1 panel A" but the label of the subtable just doesn't get picked up: I get Table 1 & ??[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\subtablename{Panel}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\Alph{subtable}}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon, belowskip=12pt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{subtable}{panel}{panels}
\Crefname{subtable}{Panel}{Panels}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Hello World}\label{tab:01}
    \begin{subtable}{\hsize}
        \caption*{Panel A: Hello}
        \label{subtab:01a}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

    \begin{subtable}{\hsize}
        \caption*{Panel B: World}
        \label{subtab:01b}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

\end{table}

I want to refer to "Table 1 panel A" \\
but the label of the subtable just doesn't get picked up \\
as follows: ~\Cref{tab:01}~\cref{tab:01a}

\end{document}
```

See picture of output below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. I believe what you want is the following:

- `\cref{subtab:01a}` instead of `\cref{tab:01a}` to avoid the “??” in the output (you had an error message: “LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:01a' on page 1 undefined on input line 32”, don't ignore error messages!);
- `\subcaption{Hello}` and `\subcaption{World}` instead of `\caption*{Panel A: Hello}` and `\caption*{Panel B: World}` for proper labels;
- `\renewcommand{\p@subtable}{}` so that `\cref{subtab:01a}` and `\cref{subtab:01b}` respectively print “panel A” and “panel B”, rather than “panel 1A” and “panel 1B.” (as requested in your question).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\subtablename}{Panel}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{\Alph{subtable}}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon, belowskip=12pt}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{subtable}{panel}{panels}
\Crefname{subtable}{Panel}{Panels}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subtable}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Hello World}\label{tab:01}
    \begin{subtable}{\hsize}
        \subcaption{Hello}
        \label{subtab:01a}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

    \begin{subtable}{\hsize}
        \subcaption{World}
        \label{subtab:01b}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}

\end{table}

\Cref{tab:01}~\cref{subtab:01a}, \cref{tab:01}~\cref{subtab:01b}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works for me. I shall keep your suggestions in mind @frougon